# Changing the contents of an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe embedded on my webpage and I'd like to edit certain parts of it using javascript. Is this possible and how would I do it?

Comment: Is the iFrame in the same domain as the parent page? Do you own the HTML/CSS/JavaScript of the iFrame?

Comment: Nope. That would make things too easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the iframe is loading content from another domain — no. You'll hit the [same origin policy.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Answer (score 3):

According to [the HTML DOM spec (level 2)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-50708718), you can reach the child DOM by using the `.contentDocument` property of the iframe's DOM node.

But, of course, no browser lets you do that across domains anymore...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the iframe document by doing this:

```
document.getElementById(iframeId).contentDocument
```

That is if you own the page loaded in the iframe.