# Change or Remove one character in an element src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `iframe` where I need to change one character.

EDIT: adding lots of additional code as this is more difficult that I first thought.

```
<iframe href="https://derpxample.com/">
<video id="post_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" loop="" preload="auto" src="https://derpxample.com/v/berp.mp4">
            <source src="https://derpxample.com/v/berp.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</iframe>
```

I'm just trying change the url protocol from `https` to `http` as simply as possible. The content source will not be changed as it's generated automagically. Thus, the following:

```
$('iframe').each(function(){
      var href = $('iframe').attr('href');
      $('iframe').attr('src',href).attr('class','postVine');
      $('video').attr('src', function(i, s) { 
      return s.replace("https", "http");
      });                 
});
```

Comment: Does the video tag have an id? Can you give it one? Would make the solution far easier.

Comment: Just edit the html source, instead of trying some javascript solution.

Comment: As Arjan also pointed out, is there any reason why you cannot simply edit the source?

Comment: By requesting a js/jq solution I thought it was apparent that changing the source is not applicable. Will be more clear, less fast in future reqs.

Comment: Have you tried `<video src="//example…>`? Then you probably won't need to change anything.

Comment: When you say you have an `iframe`, do you mean the video is inside the iframe, while your code is on the parent page?

Comment: *Why* do you need to change the protocol?

Comment: @DavidThomas so I can use `clone` and place that src up in the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
$('video').attr('src', $('video').attr('src').replace("https", "http"));
```

Edit: For the iFrame you might try something like this:

```
video = $('iframe').contents().find('video');
$(video).attr('src', $(video).attr('src').replace("https", "http"));
```

Comment: This is great elegant code. Seems to work without error, but isn't actually changing the `https` to `http`

Comment: I'd suggest simplifying this to: `$('video').attr('src', function(i, s) { return s.replace("https", "http"); );` (no need to call `.attr()` twice, and `attr()` returns a string already, so no need for `toString()`).

Comment: Thanks, David!  Removed toString() and it still worked in my sample, but I couldn't get it to work with the function on my end.  Hmmm

Answer (score 1):

Use some like this:

```
 var element = document.getElementById('my-video');
 element.src = element.str.replace('https', 'http');
```

Element:

```
 <video id='my-video' src = 'https://example... >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
videoElem.src = 'http'+videoElem.src.substr(5);
```

Comment: Only use this if you're absolutely sure that the original `src` will **always** start with `https`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
var video = document.getElementById('videoID');
video.src = video.src.replace(/^https:/, 'http:');
```

This does not assume that the src always starts with `https:`, and does not break if https occurs elsewhere in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the key to your question is that you mention an `<iframe>`.

If you're trying to access or change the contents of an iframe, you can only do that if it's loaded from the same host as your parent page.

See this question for more details: [Changing the contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563495/changing-the-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Great comment. I'm not changing the contents of an iframe, but will be using as a variable, `clone`ing or `prepend`ing it to the parent div.