# How can I change the content of an iFrame

Tags: iframe, proxy

I'm loading content in an iFrame that's from another domain. Sometimes that content contains links that I want to replace with other links or block altogether. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563495/changing-the-contents-of-an-iframe) I understand I can not change any of the content via JavaScript.

However - I was thinking of loading the contents of the iFrame via a proxy. So instead of loading www.example.com/page.html I would load www.myproxydomain.com/page.html and in the proxy I would then load from example.com and replace the page content.

Is that even technically possible?

Comment: Correct, it's not possible to change content of iframe from another origin via JavaScript. Yes, using a proxy that would perform the substitutions/filtering/blocking for you would work. Is there something specific that you need help with?

Comment: @HuguesM.thank you - yes, I'd like to know HOW that would work with a proxy - e.g. if I server the page http://www.example.com through the proxy and it contains a link to http://www.google.com and I'd like to replace that with http://www.google.com/search/ or something else - how would I do that?

Comment: This is a very broad question, and unfortunately off-topic in my opinion (not a programming question). You should ask it on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com), or perhaps [superuser](https://superuser.com). Hint: what you are after is probably a [reverse-proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy), and that can be done with apache http2 or nginx. HOW exactly will heavily depend on your system, and whatever question you'd have would be for superuser or serverfault. I'll flag this question for moderation, with some luck a moderator would remove the bounty so you don't lose the rep.

Comment: There, bounty was removed by a moderator, and you were refunded of the rep. I voted to close as "too broad". You could research how to set up a reverse proxy (if that's indeed what you want), and then if you need help, try superuser, or stackoverflow if you're stuck on an actual programming issue.

Comment: @HuguesM.thank you - that's very kind and helpful of you. I'll go ahead and research the reverse proxy indeed and see if I can it to do what I need.